# JS convert Array of Objects into JSON GroupBy Format

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to find a way to convert the following array of objects into JSON

Original Format

```
const arr = [
  {
    userid: '1000080542',
    photoname: '2c8a4709-ed7e-00a50-0da4ead1de55118-f3-1473281639’,
    datetime: ‘2020-01-24T20:46:05+11:00’
  },
  {
    userid: '1000081532',
    photoname: '73321038-c8bf-57c6e-5d803cd0a920e9a-95-1487447082',
    datetime: ‘2020-01-24T20:46:05+11:00’
  },
  {
    userid: '1000081532',
    photoname: '5c00bc65-db1b-7a394-dd65b462b9e75e2-c5-1487447019',
    datetime: ‘2020-01-24T20:46:05+11:00’
  },
  {
    userid: '1000081532',
    photoname: '986ee1e2-2f8e-bf070-0d70d2e67537835-e2-1473821119',
    datetime: ‘2020-01-24T20:46:05+11:00’
  },
  {
    userid: '1000081532',
    photoname: '09f7cde6-68c8-f462d-c01f7713a2c747f-eb-1474294185',
    datetime: ‘2020-01-24T20:46:05+11:00’
  }
]
```

Converted Format

```
{
            1000080542: {
                '2c8a4709-ed7e-00a50-0da4ead1de55118-f3-1473281639': '2020-01-24T20:46:05+11:00',
                '73321038-c8bf-57c6e-5d803cd0a920e9a-95-1487447082': '2020-01-24T20:46:05+11:00'
            },
            1000081532: {
                '5c00bc65-db1b-7a394-dd65b462b9e75e2-c5-1487447019'': '2020-01-24T20:46:05+11:00',
                '986ee1e2-2f8e-bf070-0d70d2e67537835-e2-1473821119': '2020-01-24T20:46:05+11:00',
                '09f7cde6-68c8-f462d-c01f7713a2c747f-eb-1474294185': '2020-01-24T20:46:05+11:00'
            }
        }
```

I've been trying along these lines but I'm a big off

```
obj = arr.reduce((h, y) => {
  Object.keys(y).forEach(k => {
    if (!h[k]) {
      h[k] = []
      h[k].push(y[k])
    } else if (!h[k].includes(y[k])) h[k].push(y[k])
  })
  return h
}, {})
console.log(obj)
```

thanks

Comment: What is your criteria for conversion?

Comment: It's unclear why you need `Object.keys(y)` when you know your top level key is the `userid`, and you know what the other keys are also

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
const arr = [
  {
    userid: '1000080542',
    photoname: '2c8a4709-ed7e-00a50-0da4ead1de55118-f3-1473281639',
    datetime: '2020-01-24T20:46:05+11:00'
  },
  {
    userid: '1000081532',
    photoname: '73321038-c8bf-57c6e-5d803cd0a920e9a-95-1487447082',
    datetime: '2020-01-24T20:46:05+11:00'
  },
  {
    userid: '1000081532',
    photoname: '5c00bc65-db1b-7a394-dd65b462b9e75e2-c5-1487447019',
    datetime: '2020-01-24T20:46:05+11:00'
  },
  {
    userid: '1000081532',
    photoname: '986ee1e2-2f8e-bf070-0d70d2e67537835-e2-1473821119',
    datetime: '2020-01-24T20:46:05+11:00'
  },
  {
    userid: '1000081532',
    photoname: '09f7cde6-68c8-f462d-c01f7713a2c747f-eb-1474294185',
    datetime: '2020-01-24T20:46:05+11:00'
  }
];

console.log(
  arr.reduce((accumulator, element) => {
    if (!accumulator[element.userid]) accumulator[element.userid] = {};
    
    accumulator[element.userid][element.photoname] = element.datetime;
    
    return accumulator;
  }, {})
);
```

If I understand your output example correctly, you're wanting to make the top level keys be the userids, and the contents be key value pairs of the photonames to the date times.

So you just need to put the userid in the output object as the key with a sub object as the value, and then put the photonames and datetimes in the sub object.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `reduce` with an object to store the values for each id.

```js
const arr = [
  {
    userid: '1000080542',
    photoname: '2c8a4709-ed7e-00a50-0da4ead1de55118-f3-1473281639',
    datetime: '2020-01-24T20:46:05+11:00'
  },
  {
    userid: '1000081532',
    photoname: '73321038-c8bf-57c6e-5d803cd0a920e9a-95-1487447082',
    datetime: '2020-01-24T20:46:05+11:00'
  },
  {
    userid: '1000081532',
    photoname: '5c00bc65-db1b-7a394-dd65b462b9e75e2-c5-1487447019',
    datetime: '2020-01-24T20:46:05+11:00'
  },
  {
    userid: '1000081532',
    photoname: '986ee1e2-2f8e-bf070-0d70d2e67537835-e2-1473821119',
    datetime: '2020-01-24T20:46:05+11:00'
  },
  {
    userid: '1000081532',
    photoname: '09f7cde6-68c8-f462d-c01f7713a2c747f-eb-1474294185',
    datetime: '2020-01-24T20:46:05+11:00'
  }
];
const res = arr.reduce((acc,{userid,photoname,datetime})=>{
  (acc[userid] = acc[userid] || {})[photoname] = datetime;
  return acc;
}, {});
console.log(res);
```